# Object.prototype function preventing GTM from sending signals to GA4

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I recently had one of my website pages stop sending GTM (Google Tag Manager) triggers to GA4. I tested the webpage with GTM and everything was triggering fine, but the signals weren't making it through to GA4. This webpage had already been working for months, so I couldn't figure out what the issue was.

Finally after a lot of digging I found that I had added an `Object.prototype` function into one of my JS scripts (e.g. "`Object.prototype.abc = function()`"). This prototype function seemed to be preventing communication between GTM and GA4. I'm not sure how this is even possible as the script was after any GA4 and GTM scripts and also wasn't running on anything analytics or tags related. Upon further testing I found that `Number.prototype`, `String.prototype`, and `Boolean.prototype` functions worked just fine but, for whatever reason, `Object.prototype` functions prevent GTM from sending signals to GA4.
I can get around this issue by using a standard function (e.g. "`function abc()`"), but the prototype method is often more easy to work with and more efficient.
To be clear, it's not anything in the function that is causing the issue as simply changing the prototype function to a standard function resolved the issue.

I'm just curious why this is, whether it's a bug, and if there's anyway to get around it while still using the `Object.prototype` method (without just using a standard function).

Comment: is the name of your proto function literally "abc" or was that just an example?

Comment: @GrafiCode No, that's just an example. LOL
The name doesn't seem to make a difference though.

Comment: meaning literally, whatever method's name you use, it always breaks GTM's behaviour?

Comment: @GrafiCode Yeah. 'Cause initially I thought maybe my function's name was overriding a GTM/GA4 function, but changing the name doesn't seem to make any difference.
I literally have no idea why this is. I mean I can only assume it's a bug, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: alright, that was my same doubt, that's why I was asking that. I saw you submitted a request on google help, hope somebody answers